# How to programatically clear all resources used by android application

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-package-managers

To ensure the consistency and reliability of automated android application tests, I would like to start each test with clean state. I am doing following things

```
adb shell pm clear my.project.package.activity.name
adb unistall my.project.package
adb install path_to_app
```

However app still goes to unstable state. If I install previous version of application and reinstall current version then it works other wise app goes to unstable state. I tried rebooting also, but it didn't work. I am wondering if app is holding anything in sdcard which is causing the problem. Is there any adb command I could add to make sure each launch of an application is clean and new.

Comment: "However app still goes to unstable state" -- what precisely do you mean by an "unstable state"?

Comment: App behavior is not as expected after multiple launches. Its a private application that should behave the same each run. How ever after few iterations it doesn't behave as expected. Inorder to get back to its original state I have to install previous version of app and reinstall current version.

Comment: You could _force-stop_ it first using `adb shell am force-stop my.project.package` and hope you are clearing the whole application cache not just an activity, like `adb shell pm clear my.project.package` and not just `adb shell pm clear my.project.package.activity.name`.